# Is primary valency always ionizable?

Tags: coordination-compounds

In my textbook it is written that primary valences are ionizable. I saw a case of complex $\ce{[Co(NH3)5Cl]Cl2}$  Here it is written that primary valency is 3. The $\ce{Cl}$ inside coordination sphere serves as both primary and secondary valency. Since the constituents inside are non ionizable, will it be right to day that primary valences are always ionizable?

Comment: Primary valencies need not always be ionisable.It more correctly refers to the oxidation number of central metal atom.